# Nested layout not stretching to bottom in Bootstrap4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4.4.1. In the data I want to display the first column has to be fairly wide due to the fact that the information in that column can be quite long. Because of this I have only two columns of Bootstrap's 12 available for the last three columns, so I have decided to use a nested layout.

Here is the data:

```
<style>
.my-container {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
.data-row {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
.my-col {
  border: solid;
  border-width: 2px 0px 0px 2px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.sub-col {
  background-color: pink;
  text-align: center;
}
.last-col {
  border-width: 0px 2px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.bottom-row {
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
}
</style>
<div class="container-fluid my-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-8 my-col">Entry Name</div>
    <div class="col col-2 my-col">Contact(s)</div>
    <div class="col col-2 my-col last-col">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col col-4 my-col sub-col">A</div>
          <div class="col col-4 my-col sub-col">B</div>
          <div class="col col-4 my-col sub-col">C</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row data-row">
    <div class="col col-8 my-col">Entry #1</div>
    <div class="col col-2 my-col">u1@example.com</div>
    <div class="col col-2 my-col last-col">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col col-4 my-col sub-col">A1</div>
          <div class="col col-4 my-col sub-col">B1</div>
          <div class="col col-4 my-col sub-col">C1</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row data-row">
    <div class="col col-8 my-col bottom-row">Entry #2</div>
    <div class="col col-2 my-col bottom-row">u2a@example.com u2b@example.com</div>
    <div class="col col-2 my-col bottom-row last-col">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col col-4 my-col sub-col">A2</div>
          <div class="col col-4 my-col sub-col">B2</div>
          <div class="col col-4 my-col sub-col">C2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

I want the pink portion of the `Entry #2` row to stretch all the way to the bottom. How can I do this?

Comment: I know tables are kind of old school, but any reason not to use one here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make the `container` *and* `row` full-height using `h-100`, and set the background color to pink...

https://codeply.com/p/oTK74DG4YA

```
<div class="row data-row">
    <div class="col col-8 my-col bottom-row">Entry #2</div>
    <div class="col col-2 my-col bottom-row">u2a@example.com u2b@example.com</div>
    <div class="col col-2 my-col bottom-row last-col">
        <div class="container-fluid pink h-100">
            <div class="row h-100">
                <div class="col col-4 my-col sub-col">A2</div>
                <div class="col col-4 my-col sub-col">B2</div>
                <div class="col col-4 my-col sub-col">C2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `h-100` property of Bootstrap to set height of a div to 100%. See the below link:
https://jsfiddle.net/csevimli/tchwbk95/1/